# Restricted Attribute did not register in Startup.Cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute, global-filter

I have a restricted attribute class in Asp.net Core 2.0 project and I decorate my controller with this attribute but this class is not executing  when I run the project I also put debug point on it 
here I am register this attribute

```
 services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(typeof(RestrictedAttribute));
        });


 [Area("Admin")]
[Restricted]
public class MediaController : Controller
{}
 public class RestrictedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { //Other Code } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration for your `RestrictedAttribute` is incorrect. You only need to derive from the `ActionFilterAttribute` class as that already derives from the `IActionFilter` interface.

And in your class you need to `override` the `OnActionExecuting` of the `ActionFilterAttribute` class and not implement the interface method i.e. you should not have `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting` as that is not the method that needs to be implemented.

The correct implementation is:

```
public class RestrictedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     { 
        //Other Code 
     }
}
```

In addition, you don't need to add the filter to the `config.Filters` in `AddMvc()`. It will work without that :-)

Comment: I tried adding a class that inherited from ActionFilterAttribute without modifying the Startup.cs and my OnActionExecuting method never gets hit. Any ideas?

Comment: How does one access `config.Filters` without using the `AddMvc()`?